# Wordpress media uploader

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Добрый день. Я разрабатывал сайт на вордпрессе и столкнулся с одним интересным компонентом wordpress media uploader. К сожалению, в сети я нахожу только одинокие примеры использования этого компонента, а документации по нему я найти не могу. Может кто то все же нашел основательную информацию по wp.media. Если так, то был бы рад, если бы могли ею поделиться.